# Counting consecutive repeats of a word with regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I currently have a regex pattern that matches a specific word, which includes arbitrary whitespace.

e.g. if the word was "the", my pattern will match "t   h   e" as well as "    the"

My question is, is there any way to count and track the number of *consecutive* repeats?
I am looking to return the largest amount of consecutive repeats of the word.

e.g. if my string was "the quick brown fox thethe jumped thethethe over the..."

I would want my method to return 3, not 7. Counting the total number of occurrences is very straightforward:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(t\\s*h\\s*e\\s*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

while(m.find()) {
    count++;
}
```

I would like to return the greatest number of consecutive repetitions.
Just curious if there is a way to do this with regex.

Comment: I'm afraid it is not possible in a "unique command" way since regular expressions does not have the "ability" to count. A more powerful language is need for the purpose of counting. Do you agree or I am missing something?

Comment: Yes I agree. I think that if an expression were about to "count", it wouldn't be "regular".

Comment: @VanDarg: So you want your output to be `2` as there are two consecutive repititions of `the`.

Comment: @rogelware You and VanDarg are both correct that true regular expressions cannot count.  But "regular expressions" as they are implemented in programming languages such as Perl, Python, and Java are much stronger that true regular expressions.  You can even use them to calculate if the length of a string is a prime number http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1486158

Comment: @RanRag: No sorry I wasn't clear enough. I need my method to return the number greatest consecutive repetitions.

Comment: ok. than it is not possible Maybe you can try `String p = "(t\\s*h\\s*e\\s*){3}";` it will match exactly 3 matches, so `count==1`.But it is a dirty way.

Comment: @RanRag: You just gave me an awesome idea! I'll work on it and post back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I came up with a sensible solution:

```
// Possible values for n:
// (t\\s*h\\s*e\\s*){1}
// (t\\s*h\\s*e\\s*){2}
// (t\\s*h\\s*e\\s*){3}...
public int consecutiveThe(String s) {
    int n = 0;
    while(true) {
         String expression = "(t\\s*h\\s*e\\s*){" + n + "}";
         Pattern p = Pattern.compile(expression);
         Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
         if(!m.find()) {
            break;
         }
         n++;
    }
    return (n - 1);
}
```

The idea is to loop through consecutive values of n, checking if there is a regex match. As soon as we have a value of n that is unmatched, return the number that was most previously matched in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but I believe the logic is sound. Make sure to check for off by one errors for all the positions and lengths.

```
boolean adjacentToPreviousMatch = false;
int previousPosition = 0;
int lengthOfCurrentMatch = 0;
int numSequentialMatches = 0;
ArrayList<Integer> sequences = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
while (m.find()) {
    if (numSequentialMatches > 0 ) {
        lengthOfCurrentMatch = m.end() - m.start();
        adjacentToPreviousMatch = previousPosition + lengthOfCurrentMatch == m.end();
        if (adjacentToPreviousMatch) {
            numSequentialMatches++;
        } else {
            sequences.add(numSequentialMatches);
            numSequentialMatches = 0;
        }
    }

    previousPosition = m.end();
}
```

Then you can loop through sequences to find the max sequence. Make sure to keep the trailing `\s*` in your pattern.

-Another method could be to use the plural of your pattern `"(t\\s*h\\s*e\\s*)*"` And then loop through the matches, extracting the captured string. Then, run the singular regex `"(t\\s*h\\s*e\\s*)"` on that captured string, and just do `while(m.find()) count++;` because you know they are adjacent.